# Two GPUs with Asus ROG Strix B450-F Gaming board?

Tags: graphics-cards, pcie

hope you are doing well! I have a Asus ROG Strix B450-F Gaming motherboard supplied by a 700W power supply. So far it was running nicely with 3060Ti GPU and I tried adding a RTX 2060 yesterday, but now the whole system wouldn't start in the sense that the attached monitor does not show anything, although the system seems to power up (fans are starting, etc.).

What's the best way to debug this?

Regarding the exact setup:

- 3060Ti is placed in PCIEX16_1
- 2060 is placed in PCIEX16_2
- M2_1 is occupied by a solid state disk

Standard BIOS parameters. If I swap the 3060Ti and the 2060, the 2060 card works as well, however not both at the same time.

Do you have an idea how to resolve this?

Thank you, Tom

Comment: Have you plugged in all pcie power connections?

Comment: Yes, I did. What's your hunch - might the two GPUs draw too much power from supply? I was thinking that it should be enough (120W [2060] + 200W [3060Ti]) ...

Comment: What cpu are you using? if it has a gpu (like the 3400g for example) the motherboard only supports one gpu.  Second. I've seen claims that you need to manually change the pci mode to 8x8 though I've seen no official documentation that supports this

Comment: Hi skippy! It's an AMD Ryzen 5 3600. It think it shouldnt have an additional onboard GPU, at least lspci does not show any other VGA compatible controller. Seem like I have to play with the BIOS settings a little bit.